# Why am I getting different results when I use splitted string parts using string.split(' ') and string[:-1] during itertoools.permutations() usag?

Tags: python

What's the difference between:

```
stringline = string.split(' ') 
int_part = int(stringline[1]) 
string_part = stringline[0]
```

and

```
string_part = string[:-1] 
int_part = int(string[-1:])
```

where `stringline = "HACK 2"` ?

I believed both were the same but when I try to use them to `print` `list` elements using `itertools.permutations()`, I get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string[:-1]` just removes the very last character and gives you `"HACK "` (notice the space) whereas `string.split(" ")[0]` gives you the element `"HACK"` (notice no space).

That's because split also removes the space from the original string and returns a `list` of `["HACK", "2"]`, whereas `string[:-1]` just stop return characters at `"2"`.

Comment: And the `list` returned would also include the space so even if you were to join it into a string it wouldn't be the same as `stringline[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because `string_part = string[:-1]` gives `'HACK '` with space, so `itertools.permutations()` will count the space in the iterable as well.